# Anchored adaptive banners in LinearLayout structure

Tags: java, android, android-layout, layout, admob

Good afternoon!

I am updating the normal(smart) admob banners for admob Anchored adaptive banners, I am following the example of google but I have several doubts.

I use LinearLayout as a general structure and not RelativeLayout like the google example.

When using the code to display the banner, it underlines two lines.

**Example new code banner admob:**

```
<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/ad_view_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />
```

**Yellow underline in android studios (in my code):**

```
android:layout_centerInParent="true"
```

**Message or warning:**
Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_centerInParent

```
android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
```

**Message or warning:**
Invalid layout param in a LinearLayout: layout_alignParentBottom

Example complet code banner google-admob:
https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-android-examples/blob/master/java/admob/AdaptiveBannerExample/app/src/main/res/layout/activity_my.xml

In the application the test ads are displayed well and work. But I don't like the messages of the underlined code (to avoid problems)

---

**Before I used this code for my SMART banners:**

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/ad_view_container"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    </LinearLayout>
```

Could I use the same code for Anchored adaptive banners? or does it have to be FrameLayout..?

thank you for answers

Comment: `alignParentBottom` & `centerInParent` are only for `RelativeLayout` and its children views. For `FrameLayout`, you can use `layout_gravity` and `gravity` flags.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try This**

```
android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|bottom"
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your comment. Your code works fine, no error messages. In principle admob can not say anything to modify this line right?

Comment: @lina0i0-29 Until & unless you show the loaded Ad which is also not prone to accidental clicks, it's fine to use any layout flags you want.